# Is it possible to have severals keys/certificates on a virtualhost in Apache 2?

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, mod-ssl

I would like to know how I can configure my Apache 2 (version 2.0.64) to use multiple key/certificate pairs for mutual authentication.

More precisely, I have configured my apache to accept SSL connections on port 443 by using this config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile certs/mycert.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile certs/mykey.key
     SSLCACertificateFile certs/ca.crt
     .....
</VirtualHost>
```

I have 2 aliases, let say:

```
https://myserver/project1
https://myserver/project2
```

I would like to use different key/certificate pairs (than `mykey.key`/`mycert.crt`) to authenticate client that connect to my 2nd URL (`https://myserver/project2`).

I tried with the `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` directives, but SSL directives do not seem to be supported under theses ones.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension named [*Service Name Indication*](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4366.txt) (aka *SNI*) in TLS. The TLS client indicates the name of the server it is connected to; therefore the server is able to select the correct key and certificate to use.

According to the [SNI wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support) both Apache 2 modules mod_ssl and mod_gnutls seems to support this extension and also numerous web clients

An Apache 2 configuration tutorial is available here: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Apache2/SSL_and_Name_Based_Virtual_Hosts

Comment: Hi Jcs, thanks for your response. Effectively, i did see that link but it's not really correspond to my needs.

Comment: Because my Apache use mod_jk to dispatch requests to several application servers in JAVA JEE. So that i do not have several domain names but Alias. In fact, I would exect to have some kind of config like `<Location /project1>SSLCertificateKeyfile .... SSLCertificateFile </Location>` for each project. Tell me if it doesn't seem clear for you. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have one single domain name but you want to use different server certificate based on the URL path. I don't think it is possible since the URL path is not sent by the client until the TLS handshake is done.

Answer (score 0):

Possibles solutions to do have SNI with apache2:

- Upgrade apache2 to version 2.2.x
- Compile/Install gnutls with apache2